# Accessing ListModel from ListView Section Delegate

Tags: listview, qml, qtquick2

I am new in QML/Qt Quick and I want to use ListView which has a section property. Main goal was creating collapsible ListView on my UI. My problem is Section delegate *LoadcaseListElement* needs some data from ListView's model which is *loadcaseModel* in here. But I cannot access my ListView model from my Section Delegate Element *LoadcaseListElement* . (I can access it from ListView Delegate which is *layerDelegateItem*).

The simplified code snippet is here: (The snippet does not include all js functions, element properties, etc. to achive collapsing action in favor of clarity.)

```
ListModel {
    id: loadcaseModel
    ListElement {loadcaseId:"1"; name:"LC1_Honeycomb Radome LLD3"; plyCount:"7"; layerId: "5001"}
    ListElement {loadcaseId:"1"; name:"LC1_Honeycomb Radome LLD3"; plyCount:"7"; layerId: "5002"}

}  

ListView {
    id: loadcaseListView
   
    anchors.fill: parent

    model: loadcaseModel

    delegate: LayerDelegate {
        id: layerDelegateItem

        anchors {
            left: parent.left
            leftMargin: 2
            right: parent.right
            rightMargin: 2
        }

    }

    section {
        property: "loadcaseId"
        criteria: ViewSection.FullString

        delegate: LoadcaseListElement {
            listElementLoadcaseNumber: model.loadcaseId
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help...

Enes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only data you need to access is the property that you are sectioning on, then you should be able to use the `section` attached property mentioned in the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#section.delegate-prop):

```
    section {
        property: "loadcaseId"
        criteria: ViewSection.FullString

        delegate: LoadcaseListElement {
            listElementLoadcaseNumber: section
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

You're trying to use `section` in a way that it wasn't intended, so you're running into obstacles. I recommend first organizing your model in a nested fashion. Then make your delegate smart enough to expand/hide its sub-list of elements. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33406472/qml-nested-list-view-with-highlight) is an example that shows one way to do this.

Comment: Thank you @JarMan. I already tried it and it works but actually, I want to access other properties too. Like name, plyCount etc. How can I do that?

Comment: I also tried ListView.view.model.name which is mentioned in this article but it didnt work: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html

Comment: What entry in the model would you be reading those other properties from though? The section properties group delegates that have a single property in common. But it makes no assumptions about any other properties being the same. So it doesn't give you access to them.

Comment: Actually my main goal was when user clicked list item (SectionDelegate) which represents loadcase in the UI and includes all model properties except layerId data, another menu is expanded downward between clicked list item and the next list item and thus user can see "layedId"s(ListView Delegate) which belongs to that loadcase. Any other advice to do that is highly appreciated by the way.

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: @Enes Do you want the section to be done not only on loadcaseId but also on name & plyCount?

Comment: @GrecKo, there is one section property for me and that is loadcaseId but I was thinking to add some Text Element to the SectionDelagate(LoadcaseListElement) which the text is taken from list model like name and plyCount properties but I think I cannot access them from SectionDelegate as JarMan said. In sum, This method is not suitable for creating sublists that I want as far as I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use the attached model property of the view it will work.
This will get you the first element in the model.

```
    section {
        property: "loadcaseId"
        criteria: ViewSection.FullString

        delegate: LoadcaseListElement {
            listElementLoadcaseNumber: ListView.view.model.get(0).name
        }
    }
```